# Removing certificate and re-running update-ca-certificates leaves lingering symlinks

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, symbolic-link

I have removed a (root) certicate, and re-run `update-ca-certificates`:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mine.root-ca.crt
ls -l /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1838 Feb 16  2017 something-else.crt
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

But:

```
$ ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/mine.root-ca.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Jun  4 07:22 /etc/ssl/certs/mine.root-ca.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mine.root-ca.crt
```

But that file (`/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mine.root-ca.crt`) does not exist anymore.

Actually, the `0 added, 0 removed; done.` is suspicious: it should say `1 removed`.

Certificate validation does not work anymore for the domain in question (as expected), but these two facts annoy me:

- the lingering link
- the fact that `update-ca-certificates` does not seem to do anything

I am in:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 17):

According to the man pages for update-ca-certificates, add the -f switch to remove symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs

```
-f, --fresh
          Fresh updates.  Remove symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs directory.
```

This will create a new ca-certificate.crt file without your root CA certificate and remove the symlink.

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Comment: that did not work for me. I get this message: ```Importing into legacy system store:
I already trust 131, your new list has 129
Import process completed.

Importing into BTLS system store:
I already trust 131, your new list has 129
Import process completed.
```